# Uniqueness of plurisubharmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In complex analysis there is a uniqueness theorem as,

> For holomorphic functions $f,g: \Omega \to \mathbb C$ and domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb C^n$, if $f=g$ on $D$; then $f=g$ on $\Omega$, where $D$ open in $\Omega$.

Is preceding theorem true for real valued $\mathscr{C}^2$ plurisubharmonic functions instead of holomorphic functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the special case that $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$ and $D = \{z: |\textbf{Re}(z)| < 1 \}$.  Take $f$ to be the constant zero function.

In this context, a function is plurisubharmonic iff it is subharmonic, which is to say that it has a nonnegative Laplacian.  Can you rig up a subharmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ which is zero on $D$, but not elsewhere?  Hint:  if $z = x+iy$, try to find one which is a function of $x$ only.

Comment: Thanks, this leads me to another question. I know any psh function is locally real value of a holomorphic function. If we take $u$ such it satisfies your answer, near z=1 what happens to the corresponding holomorphic function $f=u+iv$? @StevenGubkin

Comment: What you say is not true.  A PSH function need not be the real value of a holomorphic function.

Comment: It is not true that "any psh function is locally the real part of a holomorphic function". For example, in complex dimension dimension 2, any subharmonic function is psh. Psh functions even do not have to be continuous.